# How Can I increase my View Height with my UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have created one sample demo for UITextView with UIView.
I know I have asked duplicated.But could not able to solve it.

## Code Is

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{

    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = self.myTextView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;

}
```

## Image Is

[image]

[image]

[image]

My Requirement is:-
When I type on textview textview expand perfectly.But
My view (Dark BLUE) is not expand with my textview.

Please help me I want that my view should increase with UITextview height.I have used above code for increase height of textview.

Thank You

Comment: For this you need to change the frame of your view as well in 'textViewDidChange' method and set the new frame.

Comment: Using KVO to observe the `content` property of `UITextView`.

Comment: @ CosmoTrekker :-can you please give sample code because i tried to change view frame but not able to change.

Comment: Are you using `autoLayout`?

Comment: @Rikh:-No I haven't use this

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use constraint in your code. You must change the dark blue view , image and button position in your `textViewDidChange` method. You can refer to [RSKGrowingTextView](https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSKGrowingTextView)(It's based on constraint). You also can refer to [GrowingTextView](https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView)(The last update is 3 years ago.But it's based on frame)